# How to compare old and new value with Cloud Functions for Firebase with .onWrite or onchange?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Lets take the following data structure:

[image: Datastructure]

Now I want to refresh the accessTokenFacebook with a Firebase Function.
I tested two option:

1. the onWrite, and the:
2. the [onChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#monitoring_changed_values)

The onWrite looks the best to me, but with the following function:

```
exports.getFacebookAccessTokenOnchange = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/userAccountInfo/lastLogin').onWrite(event => {
  const lastLogin = event.data;
  let dateObject = new Date();
  let currentDate = dateObject.toUTCString();

  return lastLogin.ref.parent.parent.child('services').child('facebook').update({'accessTokenFacebook': currentDate});

});
```

Something happens I don'understand/can solve: when I delete a whole userUID-record (for a cleanup), the userUID-record automatically create, then only with the following path {uid}/services/facebood/accesTokenFacebook...

It seems that a deletion also triggers a onWrite.

I also tried the .onchange, but that one only triggers when there is still no accessTokenFacebook. When the change make this one, the change never triggered again.

So the next thing I want to do is a comparison between the old and new value. Do you have an example? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: `functions.database.ref(...).onWrite(e => console.log(e.data.previous.val(), e.data.val()))`

Comment: @Michael, fast response :) That looks straightforward, I'll try this as soon as possible.

Comment: @Michael, Thx! I works fine.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh you should post your comment as an answer.  It helped me out but I almost missed it because it was just a comment.  In the meantime, I'll post an answer so others don't nearly do the same, but I'll happily take mine down if you want to post yours and take the credit! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that these functions are deprecated and this is the number one search result for this subject, here is the new updated version that Cloud Functions now use.

```
exports.yourFunction = functions.database.ref('/path/{randomPath}/goes/here').onWrite((change, context) => {
    // Your value after the write
    const newVal = change.after.val();
    // Your value before the write
    const oldVal = change.before.val();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE:**
Cloud Functions recently introduced changes to the API as noted [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).

**Now (>= v1.0.0)**

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
  const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
});
```

**Before (<= v0.9.1)**

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((event) => {
  const beforeData = event.data.previous.val(); // data before the write
  const afterData = event.data.val(); // data after the write
});
```

Comment: It's worth adding that the typescript equivalent to this is:

`export const someFunction = functions.firestore
.document('SomeCollection/SomeDocumentId')
.onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const newVal = snap.after.data();
    const oldVal = snap.before.data();
});`